# como hacer que un boton realize una accion y al mismo tiempo(segunda accion) recargue la pagina con nuevos datos

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

tengo dudas al implementar este requerimiento; tengo una pagina en php en la que **muestro una tabla con 10 registros** de MYSQL mismos que puedo seleccionar para poder actualizar en la base de datos, con javascript y ajax envió los datos nuevamente a otro php para que se encargue de esta acción pero todo courre en la principal no hay redirecionamientos, y lo que necesito es lo siguiente **al momento de enviar los datos que actualizare y se procesen correctamente, de inmediato me vuelva a cargar otros 10 registros y así sucesivamente hasta terminar todos los registros de mi base de datos;** había pensado en hacer paginaciòn pero es importante que al actualizar cada 10 registros estos ya no se visualicen(puesto que ya están actualizados)no se si se podría solo pasar a las siguientes paginas y que las anteriores se inhabiliten pero no se cual opción sea mas conveniente.

NOTA:Se muestran 10 registros con valor 'NC' no capturado de los cuales el usuario elige "Guardar" estos elegidos se actualizan con un valor 'CA' DE Capturado en la base de datos y los NO SELECCIONADOS de igual manera se actualizan con otro valor 'E' de eliminado, aunque para el usuario estos no tienen importancia, internamente si; por eso debo mostrar de 10 en 10 los registros.

anexo mi código en Javascript/Ajax y mi php/html:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
}); 
    $('#f1').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id_select= [];
    var no_select=[];
    var i=0;
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){//SE LLAMA A CADA UNO DE LOS CHECKBOX 
    
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            //sweetAlert( "Notas Guardadas", "Envio Exitoso", "success");
            id_select.push($(this).val());
            
        }
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')){    
            no_select.push($(this).val());
            ++i;
            console.log("Id NO SELECCIONADO   "+ no_select);
            //sweetAlert( "Porfavor elije una opciòn  ", "Error de Envio", "error");
        }else{
            console.log("Id SELECCIONADO   "+ id_select);
       
        $.ajax({
                url: "views/upd_notas.php",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json",
                data: {'id_nota':id_select, 'no_select':no_select}
        }).done(function(info){
            //$('#mensaje').html(info);
            sweetAlert("Datos Enviados", "Envio Exitoso", "success");
        }); 
        //alert(JSON.stringify(id_select));//PARA FINES DIDACTTICOS DE VER QUE LOS id_select SE ENVIABAN CORRECTAMENTE
        //alert(JSON.stringify(no_select));//PARA FINES DIDACTTICOS DE VER QUE LOS no_select SE ENVIABAN CORRECTAMENTE
        }
       
    });
    });
```

```html
<?php

include_once 'bin/init.php';

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">
    <title>Busca_Notas</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/general.css">

</head>
<form name="f1" id="f1" method="post">   

<body>

<?php include "views/".$p.".php"; 
    $sql = "select n.id_nota, n.url, n.palabra, p.cliente, n.estado  from notas n
join palabras p on p.palabra = n.palabra
ORDER BY n.id_nota asc
LIMIT 10";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){ 

    echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0>";
    
    echo "<tr>
    <th colspan=6 bgcolor=black class=tagline align=center><h4>NOTAS</h4></th>
    <tr  class=tagline align='center'>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Url</th>
    <th>Cliente</th>
    <th>Palabra</th>
    <th>Estado</th>
    <th>Selecciona</th>
    </tr>";
    $cont=1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        echo "<tr id=$row[id_nota]>
        <td align='center'>$cont</td>
        <td><a href='$row[url]'>$row[url]</a></td>
        <td align='center'>$row[cliente]</td>
        <td align='center'>$row[palabra]</td>
        <td align='center'>En Proceso</td>
       <td>
            
            <input type=checkbox id='notas' value=$row[id_nota] name='id_nota[]'/>
            <label for=checkbox>Guardar</label>        
           
        </td>
        </tr>";      
        $cont++; 
    }
    echo "</table>";
   
}

?>   
 
<br>
<input type="submit"  name="Enviar" value="Enviar" id="BotonEnviar"  />
 <br>
 <!--<div id="mensaje"></div>SE UTILIZA INTERNAMENTE PARA VALIDAR EL ENVIO DE DATOS A PHP-->
</form>
<script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/valida.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no te sirve un time interval para que valla actualizando cada cierto tiempo?

Answer (score 0):

No necesariamente tienes que hacerlo con AJAX, podrias poner que los datos se envien de forma natural con un formulario y que lo primero que haga tu script php sea realizar el cambio que deseas y segundo seleccionar los siguientes registros identificandolos por el campo que mencionas que te dice si ya fueron editados o no.

Ahora si realmente necesitas hacerlo por AJAX necesitarias primero separar tu logica para la seleccion de los datos a un script php independiente de la vista html para que asi tu función ajax apunte a este script realize el cambio en tus registros y posteriormente seleccione los nuevos que necesitas con la condiciones necesarias y los devuelva en formato JSON y con javascript pintarlos en tu vista, ahora si no quieres pintarlos con javascript puedes recargar la página al finalizar la ejecución de tu funcion AJAX con:

```
location.reload()
```

Aún que asi ya no tendria mucho sentido haber usado ajax y si usas esta ultima opción tendrias que tener tu logica para la selección en la vista.

Comment: podrías darme un ejemplo de como hacerlo sin AJAX porfavor...